# How to auto login session in VNC Server

Tags: vncserver

On Ubuntu when I login using Tight VNC Viewer client it shows me two sessions.

What I want is as soon as I start VNC server(using `vncserver -geometry 1600x900`   it should automatically login into specific session.

EDIT: My Ubuntu has 8GB RAM. Daily during 12pm there occurs peak processing which takes up too much of memory. So during this 1 hour I don't want VNC Server/Firefox to take up any memory. After 1PM VNC Server should automatically startup thru Cron, that should start Firefox which has some Extensions which will execute some tasks. So VNC Server will be killed at 11:55am next day to free the memory.
But when it starts next time at 1pm it does not run Firefox because it stops and asks me to select which session I want to login and when I select a session then only it logs in and starts Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `.vnc` file with the connection details inside.

You may create that file from after connecting to the server.
The method varies among implementations, but you might have a "Save" button
in the TightVNC toolbar.

If TightVNC has registered itself as handler to this file-extension,
executing the file will directly launch TightVNC.

If it didn't, you might need to call the TightVNC executable with this file as
parameter. The exact parameter to use also varies between TightVNC versions,
so consult the documentation.

Comment: Sorry I was talking about server side settings only. The VNC server will start thru crontab. But I want the Firefox within it to start running a Web Extension. However after starting it is getting stuck at the session page and firefox isn't starting till I login. So Tight VNC client etc will not come into play now

Comment: Sorry, I took the question to be for a much simpler scenario. Could you please add to your post more detail about what exactly you are doing and your Linux distribution. For example, I don't get what is "Firefox within it".